# JPA native query with same column twice

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am a JPA newbie and wanted to have a JPA native query for a single table (below) which I would like to fetch in my @Entity based class called TestRequest. It has a column 'RequestTime' that is fetched with DAYNAME() and then with DATEDIFF() functions.

```
SELECT TestRequest.Id AS Id
               , TestRequest.RequestTime AS RequestTime
               , DAYNAME(TestRequest.RequestTime) AS RequestDay
               , TestRequest.StatusMessage AS StatusMessage
               , DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), TestRequest.RequestTime) AS HowLongAgo
            FROM TestRequest
                     LEFT JOIN TestRun
                               ON TestRequest.TestRunId = TestRun.Id
           WHERE Requestor = '[NAME]'
           ORDER BY Id DESC
```

Is there any way in which the column (fetched second time as HowLongAgo) be set into a property which is not mapped to a table column within the TestRequest class? Are there any field level annotations for this?

Comment: maybe you could add property _HowLongAgo_ in your entity and mark it as _@Transient_ ?

Comment: Thanks, I guess that would work. And do I just compute the Dayname() and Datediff() using standard Java?

Comment: yeah, maybe you are better off if you compute howLongAgo in your Entity. but you could do in you query

Comment: Are you sure it can be done in the query? If I understood correctly @Transient does not fetch anything from the query...

Comment: I think this article answers it in detail - https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-calculated-properties-with-jpa-and-hibernate-formula-annotation/

Comment: use Vlad's approach if it fits your needs... optional you could compute the transient properties is the getter or fill them via an extra constructor...

Comment: I have resolved same issue using interface-based projections, please take a look at my suggestion and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Interface-based projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections):

You will need to create an interface that define the getters for each field in your projection like:

```
public interface RequestJoinRunProjection {
  int getId();
  LocalDate getRequestTime();
  String getMessage();
  String getRequestDay();
  Long getHowLongAgo();
}
```

Then you define a method on your Repository that has the native query you want to run:

```
public interface TestRequestRepository extends CrudRepository<TestRequest, Long> {

  // Any other custom method for TestRequest entity

  @Query(value = "SELECT trq.Id AS id " +
      "   , trq.RequestTime AS requestTime " +
      "   , DAYNAME(trq.RequestTime) AS requestDay " +
      "   , trq.StatusMessage AS statusMessage " +
      "   , DATEDIFF(YEAR, CURDATE(), trq.RequestTime) AS howLongAgo " +
      "FROM TestRequest trq " +
      "         LEFT JOIN TestRun tr " +
      "                   ON trq.TestRunId = tr.Id " +
      "WHERE Requestor = ?1 ORDER BY Id DESC"), nativeQuery = true)
  List<RequestJoinRunProjection> findTestSumary(String name);
}
```

Notice query must be native since you are using database functions, also the column names must match the setters of your projection interface(following bean rules), so use `AS` in order to change the names in your query.

I strongly suggest you test your query on h2 before injecting into `@Query` annotation. `DATEDIFF` requires 3 parameters.

Comment: Thanks for this! I will give this a try and let you know if it works for me.